# ISCE script error

Tags: python, linux, insar

I am trying to run the command-line script [`make_single_reference_stack_isce`](https://github.com/isce-framework/isce2/blob/main/contrib/timeseries/prepStackToStaMPS/bin/make_single_reference_stack_isce) but I am getting the below error. This is an executable shell script and `input_file` argument is a text file.

If I remove this error, it shows another error that the file ended abruptly. The code was provided by ISCE2 so couldn't be a syntax error. I believe there is some issue with the exporting part.

code:

```
make_single_reference_stack_isce input_file
```

error:

```
make_single_reference_stack_isce: line 77: syntax error near unexpected token `('
make_single_reference_stack_isce: line 77: `        echo \- slc_stack_baseline_path as the path to the baseline folder for the stack, with files containing single baseline value as AAAAAAAA_YYYYMMDD.txt or grid of baselines as YYYYMMDD (isce readable file with xml information), and with the baseline in m units.'
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Coding problems here need to contain both the relevant code and error message, in the body of the Question, as text. Images are not legible on all devices and not searchable by others with the same problem.

Comment: This isn't a coding question. It's an issue with a command-line application. The question contains the command line used and the error as text in addition to the screenshot.